# Adding parameters to function in script editor for google sheets

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, web-scraping, parameters

I am trying to teach myself some coding and scraping from websites. But I am having an issue with adding parameters. Without parameters I need to adjust the function which is not preferable. This is the working function without the parameters

```
function import1() {
  var  html, content = '';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.fundsquare.net/security/summary?idInstr=275136");


  if (response) {
    html = response.getContentText();
    if (html) content = html.match(/<span class="surligneorange">([\d.]*).*<\/span>/)[1];
  }                                
   return content;
}
```

This is how I adjusted it so it has parameters:

```
function importval(url, name) {
  var found, html, content = '';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  found = "/<span class="+name+">([\d.]*).*<\/span>/"

  if (response) {
    html = response.getContentText();
    if (html) content = html.match(found)[1];
  }                                
   return content;
}
```

However, It doesn't work. It gives different errors when I try to adjust it. The issue is with the `URL` with some errors and with the `name` with others. With this code above the error is that the `url` variable has no value. I am unsure how I can make the formula with the parameters

I understand that the code `found = "/<span class="+name+">([\d.]*).*<\/span>/"` wont work with every website but if I can make this work I can figure out how to adjust it so it works for the websites I want it for. Now it will only work for a span class, but this can be changed so it works for more websites (I think).

**Edit 6-6 16:05** this is a question about the solution

This is the code that the match should find:
`(/<span class="surligneorange">([\d.]*).*<\/span>/)[1];`

this is the code, you wrote 
`("<span class=\""+name+"\">([\\d.]*).*<\\/span>")`.

What is the reason the two `\`  in `\""+name+"\"`  are needed? When playing around with it it seems to be important for showing what part is a string and what part is a variable that should be implemented. But I am unsure how it works because `"<span class=\"` includes the `\` but `"+name+"\"` here it seems to be in between the `" "`. Why is one `\` included and one on its own between `" "`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- When you want to create the regex using the variable, please use `RegExp`.
- Although I'm not sure about the URL you want to use, when the retrieved value from the URL is not matched with the regex, `html.match(found)` becomes `null`. In this case, your script occurs an error. So I modified about this.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function importval(url, name) {
  var found, html, content = '';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  found = new RegExp("<span class=\""+name+"\">([\\d.]*).*<\\/span>");  // <--- Modified
  if (response) {
    html = response.getContentText();
    if (html) {
      content = html.match(found);  // <--- Modified
      if (content && content.length == 2) {  // <--- Added
        content = content[1];
      }
    }
  }
  return content;
}
```

- When `name` is `surligneorange`, the regex becomes `/<span class="surligneorange">([\d.]*).*<\/span>/`.
- I could confirm that when `url` and `name` are `https://www.fundsquare.net/security/summary?idInstr=275136` and `surligneorange`, respectively, `31.15` is retrieved.
- In this modified script, when the retrieved value from the URL is not matched with the regex, `null` is returned.

#### Note:

- Although you have already mentioned in your question, I also think that all URLs, that you want to use, might not be able to be used for this script.  I'm worry about this.

#### Reference:

- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

### Added:

About your additional question, I would like to answer as follows.

In this case, as a simple way for understanding it, how about checking the value of `found`? In the current stage, now, it has already been found that `/<span class="surligneorange">([\d.]*).*<\/span>/` is the correct value.

When `name` is `surligneorange`,

- `found` of `found = new RegExp("<span class="+name+">([\d.]*).*<\/span>");` is as follows.

  - `/<span class=surligneorange>([d.]*).*<\/span>/`
- `found` of `found = new RegExp("<span class=\""+name+"\">([\\d.]*).*<\\/span>");` is as follows.

  - `/<span class="surligneorange">([\d.]*).*<\/span>/`
  - This is the same with the correct value.

In this case, `<\/span>` and `<\\/span>` were the same result.

In [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), `When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are necessary.` can be seen.

Comment: Thank you again for the comments. It works for all the information I want to retrieve from this website. I am going to see how I can make it work for the other websites. I have added  a one question to understand exactly what you changed!

Comment: @Mees Mouwen Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I added the answer to my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Yes thank you. I see now why it's important but need to learn the rules of general expression more. My goal for this week is reached at least. I will read through some documents to understand better how regex works. You have made me come a far way already so thanks for your time! I probably will come back in the near future!